# convert json object into java object

Tags: java, json, object

```
class A{}

class B{}

class C{ 
       private Map<A,B> myMap;
   }

class Test{

public static void main(String [] args)
{ 
      Map classMap=new HashMap();
       classMap.put("myMap","?");
       C c = (C) JSONObject.toBean(jsonObject, C.class,classMap);
}

}
```

I am using "net.sf.json" library for converting json object into java object.Here in class C there is a map, so how to convert it into Java Object. Here jsonObject is a json representation of class C.
My question is how to convert a json object into Java Object if java Object containing Map

I am a beginner, any help will be very thankful.

Comment: Where is json object?

Comment: Here jsonObject is a json representation of class C

Comment: Well, you have the (incomplete) code - does it work?

Comment: It is sample code i put here, My coode is very complex and I cannot put here, so I make a dummy code same to my Problem.

Comment: My question is how to convert a json object into Java Object if java Object containing Map<A,B>

Comment: I really recommend to use Gson library.

Answer (score 0):

I have used jackson library and in that when a json is passed to the java code and if you want to parse that json into a java object you need to have a class which contains all the property which are present in the json string.

for example:

```
jsonString=
{
 'firstname':'json',
 'lastname':'jack'
}
```

will be equivalent to a java class which contains both the property as

```
class A {
 String firstname;
 String lastname;
}
```

so if you accept the string from frontend as the object of class A it works

like

```
public void (A objectofA){

}
```

and you call this method from front end and pass a json string using json library it will work and have faith in your work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in "net.sf.json"
Try to see how serialization works in "net.sf.json". Probably, you can go from there.

This is how it is done using jackson, (one of the commenters has tried to explain you an approach using this)

```
//you need to import:
//import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValueAsString(c) //--> This gives Json String
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can work, as JSON cannot represent arbitrary objects as keys in maps. In JSON keys have to be strings. So in your example Map would only work if A was String.

Then you could say:

```
classMap.put("myMap",B.class);
```